# Fatal: Unknown scheme: SHA512-CRYPT - is This mac related?

Tags: password, encryption, mysql

You can see from the output of the samples shows in the first case, that SHA512-CRYPT seems to be Unknown.
The code I used is from a Linux based tutorial on setting up Postfix+Dovecot+MySQL on a site. Everything is generally going ok, apart from this bit. There are some others unknown as well. The codes used to create my database of passwords follows these output examples.

```
MacMini:~ robert$ sudo doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p 123456
Fatal: Unknown scheme: SHA512-CRYPT
MacMini:~ robert$ sudo doveadm pw -s SHA512 -p 123456
{SHA512}ujJTh2rta8ItSm/1PYQGxq2GQZXtFEq1yHYhtsIztUi66uaVbfNG7IwX9eoQ817jy8UUeX7X3dMUVGTioLq0Ew==
MacMini:~ robert$ sudo doveadm pw -s SHA256 -p 123456
{SHA256}jZae727K08KaOmKSgOaGzww/XVqGr/PKEgIMkjrcbJI=
MacMini:~ robert$ sudo doveadm pw -s MD5 -p 123456
{MD5}$1$.mAQzPhO$6v/WxTUt.Y1lhopkMarEb0
MacMini:~ robert$ sudo doveadm pw -s MD5-CRYPT -p 123456
{MD5-CRYPT}$1$gNkYwx/o$3nQLmUIPOBmZdR/e/EXFV1
MacMini:~ robert$ sudo doveadm pw -s BLF-CRYPT -p 123456
Fatal: Unknown scheme: BLF-CRYPT
MacMini:~ robert$ sudo doveadm pw -s SHA512 -p 1pass66U!
{SHA512}EuuO6BAt+bgzXIOw7XIdiVBFwdEZ2tGqHOJ/DSTSkD+ikw7GQQo+KtHSta7p3KNv2AEVKtfOuyl5UeCEqnKogg==
MacMini:~ robert$ sudo doveadm pw -s SHA256-CRYPT -p 1pass66U!
Fatal: Unknown scheme: SHA256-CRYPT
MacMini:~ robert$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
MacMini:~ robert$ cd
```

My MySQL Version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

The MySQL code used to create the user/password table. Which seems to work fine, and creates the table as it should - even though the resulting password doesn't appear to be quite right for SHA512-CRYPT

```
INSERT INTO `mailserver`.`virtual_users`
  (`id`, `domain_id`, `password` , `email`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', ENCRYPT('firstpassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))), 'email1@example.com'),
  ('2', '1', ENCRYPT('secondpassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))), 'email2@example.com');
```

What it actually creates is this: This is not a SHA512-CRYPT password??

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mailserver.virtual_users;

3 |         1 | $6jxK9DWPBrAc | robert@zeus.example.com
```

Just to be clear,. this is the section of the Dovecot configs that deals with handling this. BUT.. On the MAC-Mini, SHA512-CrYPT is unknown.

```
# List of supported schemes is in
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes
#
default_pass_scheme = SHA512-CRYPT
```

So the question is, what Encryption should I be using, and is this an Apple thing, or a MySQL thing?

thanks
Robert

Comment: Looks like a question about `dovecot`.  Is there a `dovecot` mailing list where you can ask for help from the dovecot experts?

Comment: Since found out that SHA512-CRYPT and some others not available natively on Macs